# Voltage Regulation Problem

Tags: voltage, transformer

[image]

I am confused with this problem. I think it is not in accordance with the defination of voltage regulation. I will show my work.

Vol Reg = Rpu*cosphi + Xpu*sinphi = 0.03*1+0.06*0 = 0.03

0.03 = (Vnl-Vfl)/Vfl = (200-Vfl)/Vfl

gives Vfl=154V which doesn't match any options

0.03= (Vnl-Vfl)/Vnl = (200-Vfl)/200

gives Vfl=194 which matches with option A

The first one was taught in my class but second one gives the result. Please help me with this problem.

Comment: This is not a site for automatic solution of your homework problems...

Comment: I have already done the solution myself here. I am trying to understand what is voltage regulation.

Comment: Instead of blindly believing what you have from your class, understand what the algebra means and how it is derived. When you figure that out you will have your correct formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voltage regulation says how well a constant voltage is maintained by the supply/transformer. It can be expressed in fraction of either no-load voltage or full-load voltage.

If in terms of no-load voltage as the reference:
$$ r = (V_{NL} - V_{FL}) / V_{NL}$$
If in terms of full-load voltage as the reference:
$$ r = (V_{NL} - V_{FL}) / V_{FL}$$

In case of transformers, first formula is generally used. It is more logical to use the no-load voltage at the secondary as the reference, and to express regulation in terms of the voltage deviation from it, according to the load connected by the end user.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwikrIeLpOfYAhXMpI8KHQqfCi4QFggwMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fnptel.ac.in%2Fcourses%2F108106071%2Fpdfs%2F1_9.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3UHkKwuYPqh3yn9A0F17jG Please refer this.